# Path between two Topos() locations: determine latitude and longitude where a given altitude is reached

Tags: python, skyfield

I am quite new to field of orbital mechanics and currently struggling a bit with the following problem, which should be quite easy to solve with Skyfield, yet I am a bit overwhelmed by all the different coordinate systems and the translation between them.

I have a `Topos` location on Earth and a `Topos` location of a LEO satellite. I am considering the line-of-sight between them. I want to determine the latitude and longitude of the position along this path, where it intersects a specific layer of the atmosphere.

An example would be the mesosphere and an existing dataset on its properties at around 100km that is given based on latitude and longitude. The intersection would allow me to better understand the interaction these properties have on the communication with the satellite.

I tried doing it with Skyfield directly, but only end up with an `Apparent` object that I cannot convert back to latitude, longitude on Earth. First, I trigonometrically determined the distance from Earth to the point, where the height of 100km is reached.

Then, I took the position on Earth and used the unchanged elevation, azimuth to keep the direction of the path and finally added the calculated distance to arrive at this position. I think I need to get a `Geocentric` object to use `subpoint()` in order to get the desired latitude, longitude of this location.

This is what I have so far:

```
from skyfield.api import load, Distance
from skyfield.toposlib import Topos
import numpy as np

ts = load.timescale()

earth_position = Topos('52.230039 N', '4.842402 E', elevation_m=10)
space_position = Topos('51.526200 N', '5.347795 E', elevation_m=625 * 1000)

difference = (space_position - earth_position).at(ts.now()).altaz()

distance_to_height = 100 / np.sin(difference[0].radians)

position = earth_position.at(ts.now()).from_altaz(alt_degrees=difference[0].degrees, az_degrees=difference[1].degrees, distance=Distance(km=distance_to_height))
```

I have gone through the documentation multiple times, and stumbled upon `frame_latlon(frame)` for Generic ICRF objects, but am not sure how to further proceed.

Trying it completely trigonomatrically with the latitudes and longitudes didn't yield the desired results either.

Unfortunately I do not really have any validated results that could be used to solve this problem more easily. Imagining it again trigonometrically, it is obvious that an increase in altitude of the satellite position would move the lat, lon of the intersection closer to the position on Earth. Decreasing the altitude would then move this intersection closer to the satellite.

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of the approximate “desired results” for this particular pair of positions? That would give folks wanting to develop an answer the confidence that they are producing the numbers you want, without having to guess whether their answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an interesting problem, which Skyfield’s API provides no easy way to ask about; if you could outline the larger problem that will be solved by knowing the intersection of the line-of-sight with a particular altitude, then it is possible that a routine addressing that problem could be written for future users tackling the same question.

In the meantime:

1. To get your script running I had to import `Distance` from `api`.
2. The name `dis` was not recognized, so I replaced it with `distance_to_height`, hoping that it was the name intended.
3. Calling `ts.now()` is giving you a slightly different date and time on each call. While the script runs so fast that it probably does not matter, I have for clarity pivoted to calling `now()` only once at the beginning of the script, which is also slightly faster than calling it repeatedly. (Actually in this case it’s much faster, because the rotation matrices only get computed once rather than having to be computed over again for each separate time object, but that’s a hidden detail that’s not easy to see.)
4. I suspect a problem with your geometry: the `100 / sin()` maneuver would only work if the Earth were flat, I think? But maybe you are always dealing with nearly-overhead satellites and so the error is manageable? (Or maybe I am mis-imagining the geometry; feel free to provide a diagram if the math is in fact correct.)
5. For readability I’ll give the components of `altaz()` names rather than numbers.

With those tweaks in place,
I think the answer is that you need to manually construct a `Geocentric`
position by adding together the position of the observer
and the relative vector you have created
between the observer and the kind-of-100km point along the line of sight.
Having to take a manual step like this suggests a possible area
where Skyfield can improve.
Here is how it looks in code:

```
from skyfield.api import load, Distance
from skyfield.positionlib import Geocentric
from skyfield.toposlib import Topos
import numpy as np

ts = load.timescale()
t = ts.now()

earth_position = Topos('52.230039 N', '4.842402 E', elevation_m=10)
space_position = Topos('51.526200 N', '5.347795 E', elevation_m=625 * 1000)

alt, az, distance = (space_position - earth_position).at(t).altaz()

distance_to_height = 100 / np.sin(alt.radians)

e = earth_position.at(t)
p = e.from_altaz(alt_degrees=alt.degrees, az_degrees=az.degrees, distance=Distance(km=distance_to_height))

g = Geocentric(e.position.au + p.position.au, t=t)
s = g.subpoint()
print(s)
print(s.elevation.km, '<- warning: 100/sin() did not produce exactly 100')
```

The result I see is:

```
Topos 52deg 06' 30.0" N 04deg 55' 51.7" E
100.02752954478532 <- warning: 100/sin() did not produce exactly 100
```

And for the future,
I have added some thoughts to the Skyfield `TODO.rst` file
that together might move towards unlocking a more idiomatic way
to perform this kind of calculation in the future —
though I suspect that a few more steps even beyond these will be necessary:

https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/commit/ba1172a0ccfef84473436d9d7b8a7d7011344cbd

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I included a bit more context on the goal and also incorporated your remarks, which I could have noticed right away. 

Concerning 4) I think the error is generally manageable and acceptable in my case. As the satellite is essentially moving around the Earth, having a latitude, longitude subpoint at a high altitude all the time, it felt acceptable doing it trigonometrically. At least this is how I imagined `subpoint()` is computing the location of a satellite on Earth. Even though it is probably way more complicated.